# Whether Clickhouse supporting detecting newly added kafka partitions during consume message from a kafka topic

Tags: clickhouse

I am trying to use clickhouse to concusme the kafka messages. It all works fine, but recently we added some partitions to the kafka topic, but the newly added partitions can not been detected and consumed by clickhouse. Is it due to clickhouse not supporting this?

Answer (score 0):

It should work without any manual interventions. What CH version do you use?

try `detach table your_table_kafka_engine`,  `attach table your_table_kafka_engine`